# Glade is crashing in Ubuntu 13.10 when I load a file done in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 13.10, glade

I made this file in Ubuntu 12.04 and all is working perfect with Glade:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~costales/gui-ufw/gufw-13.10/view/227/data/ui/preferences.ui

But in Ubuntu 13.10 and Glade 3.14.2, when I'm opening that file, I get this dump:

```
(glade:2626): GladeUI-ERROR **: Unable to get GladeWidget for internal child vbox
```

It's the line:

```
<child internal-child="vbox">
```

Please, how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue with Glade on Ubuntu 13.10.
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade/+bug/1242865

The temporary fix as provided in comment #25 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade/+bug/1242865/comments/25) works fine for me.